# Set background based on time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two images that will act as the backgrounds to the page:

```
<img src="http://www.narm.org.uk/home/images/Daylight%20design.jpg" id="background" alt="day" />
<img src="http://www.aphoenix.ca/photoblog/photos/NighttimeColours.jpg" id="h_background" alt="night" />
```

The CSS will hide one and display the other:

```
#background {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
}

#h_background {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
```

The javascript should check what time it is and set the correct background.  If the seconds are > 30, then have one background.  If not, set the other one.

```
function setBackground() {

if (secs > 30) {
    $('#h_background').attr('id', 'background');
    $('#background').attr('id', 'h_background');
}

else if (secs < 30) {
    $('#background').attr('id', 'h_background');
    $('#h_background').attr('id', 'background');
}

setTimeout(function() {setBackground()}, 1000);

}​
```

What'd I'd like to be able to do is add a transition to the new background when the time switches.

Currently, the background will switch automatically but it's not smooth.  Any thoughts on what would be an effective way to accomplish this? Below is the complete jsfiddle that shows what I have so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/gkMVf/2/

Comment: I answered a similar question the other day: http://jsfiddle.net/PKqGk/

Comment: Here's the demo updated with your images: http://jsfiddle.net/PKqGk/1/ Note that I'm maintaining the aspect ratio of the images and centering them horizontally instead of stretching them.

Comment: Why are you changing the background if less or more than 30 seconds if you don't mind me asking? Just that you could use a longer timeout like 10 seconds.

Comment: @Bruno I'm just using this for the short term - I'll eventually be using it for finding the time of day and setting one background or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment with the [opacity](http://www.css3.info/preview/opacity/) thats css3 has to offer. I would create a more controlled fade in fade out effect for a smoother transition. One image would gradually increase in opacity, whilst the other would gradually decrease in opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can use the fadeIn and fadeOut functions.

```
function setBackground() {

    if (secs > 30) {
        $('#h_background').fadeIn();
        $('#background').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('#background').fadeIn();
        $('#h_background').fadeOut();
    }

    setTimeout( setBackground, 1000 );

}
```

This does not rely on CSS3 or HTML5 so good browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

As another user mentioned, you could try using CSS3 transitions instead.

With some CSS like so:

```
.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.background.hidden {
    opacity: 0;   
}
```

Then some javascript like so:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.background').toggleClass('hidden');
}, 30000)​
```

You can get it to work a bit simpler. Try the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkMVf/3/